# Testing a constructor with a database component

Tags: elixir, integration-testing, phoenix-framework, ecto

I have a module for `Happymeal` which takes consists of `:food` (String) and `:toy` (simple database object with `:id` as primary key)

The constructor looks like this:

```
defmodule Myapp.Happymeal do

  alias Myapp.{Repo, Toy}

  defstruct [
    :toy,
    :food
  ]

  @type t :: %__MODULE__{
          toy: Toy,
          food: String
        }

  def new(%{toy_id: toy_id, food: food}) do
    toy = Repo.get(Toy, toy_id)

    {:ok,
     %__MODULE__{
       toy: toy,
       food: food
     }}
  end
end
```

When I run `Myapp.Happymeal.new(%{toy_id: 1, food: "burger"})` in `iex` I get back a `Happymeal` as expected.

However, when I run this from a test:

```
defmodule MyappTest do
  use ExUnit.Case 

  describe "Happymeal tests" do
    test "Happymeal can be created" do
      {:ok, happymeal} = Myapp.Happymeal.new(%{toy_id: 1, food: "burger"})

      IO.inspect(happymeal)
    end
  end
end
```

... I get an error:

```
** (DBConnection.OwnershipError) cannot find ownership process for #PID<0.341.0>.

 When using ownership, you must manage connections in one
 of the four ways:

 * By explicitly checking out a connection
 * By explicitly allowing a spawned process
 * By running the pool in shared mode
 * By using :caller option with allowed process

 The first two options require every new process to explicitly
 check a connection out or be allowed by calling checkout or
 allow respectively.

 The third option requires a {:shared, pid} mode to be set.
 If using shared mode in tests, make sure your tests are not
 async.

 The fourth option requires [caller: pid] to be used when
 checking out a connection from the pool. The caller process
 should already be allowed on a connection.

 If you are reading this error, it means you have not done one
 of the steps above or that the owner process has crashed.

 See Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox docs for more information.
 code: {:ok, happymeal} = Myapp.Happymeal.new(%{toy_id: 1, food: "burger"})
```

How can I make this style of constructor work from within a phoenix test?

EDIT:  My `test_helper.exs` looks like this:

```
ExUnit.start()

Ecto.Adapters.SQL.Sandbox.mode(Myapp.Repo, :manual)
```

Comment: Which database are you using?

Comment: @JustinWood Postgres, default configuration

Comment: There must be something more going on than what you have shared. Either someone changed something, must likely in `MyApp.Case`, or there is more going on in your test. Are you spawning any additional processes to do the work?

Comment: Can you please share your `test_helper.exs` @MarkKaravan

Comment: @ZubairNabi  Added the test_helper in the edit above

Comment: In test helper. Can you add Application.ensure_all_started(:my_app_name) just after the ExUnit.start()